# Get the first element of a field in an Altair transform_joinaggregate

Tags: python, altair

I would like to get the 1st element (so the one with the lowest index of the df) in a transform_joinaggregate and use that in a grouped transform_calculate, for example to subtract it.

I can calculate it in pandas like below, but I am looking for a way to do it in Altair.

The 'offset' column below is what I want to get in Altair:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]
x = [1,2,3] * 2
cat = ['a','a','a','b','b','b']

df = pd.DataFrame({'cat':cat, 'x':x, 'y':y})
df['offset'] = df.groupby('cat')['y'].transform('first')

line = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    color='cat:N'
)

line2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(opacity=0.4).transform_calculate(
    y2 = alt.datum.y - alt.datum.offset
).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y2:Q',
    color='cat:N'
)
line + line2
```

Which gives this plot:

[image: plot1]

I think I might need to use the "values" aggregation and the "slice" expression but I can't figure it out. The below returns an empty chart (NaNs).

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).transform_joinaggregate(
    vals = 'values(y)',
    groupby = ['cat']
).transform_calculate(
    corr = alt.expr.slice(alt.datum.vals, 0, 1),
    y2 = alt.datum.y - alt.datum.corr
).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y2:Q',
)
```

Comment: If you calculate directly without using toransform_joinaggregate(), y2 will be subtracted by the offset value. `alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).transform_calculate(y2 = alt.datum.y - alt.expr.slice('values(y)', 0, 1)).encode(...)`

Comment: Thanks. While that doesn't throw an error, I get an empty chart (with NaNs). My first example was maybe too simple, I would like to use it in a grouped joinagg. I also changed my trial code to splitting the aggregate in transform_joinaggregate and do the calculations in transform_calculate.